# Timeout in MVC application

Tags: identityserver3

I've configured IDS and some applications in an MVC app using Owin. (See code at the end of the post).

The issue I have is timing out an MVC action. I've configured the Client (idsClientId) to have the following settings:

IdentityTokenLifetime: 1
AccessTokenLifetime: 1
AuthorizationCodeLifetime: 1

It's set to implicit flow etc...

I expected the app to timeout when I clicked on a MVC action but it's not. Any help appreciated.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = idsAuthority,
                ClientId = idsClientId,
                Scope = "openid profile roles",
                ResponseType = "id_token token",
                RedirectUri = idsRedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = idsPostLogoutRedirectUri,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                    {
                        var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                            Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                            Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                        // get userinfo data
                        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                            new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
                            n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                        var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
                        userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(ui => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ui.Item1, ui.Item2)));

                        // keep the id_token for logout
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                        // add access token for sample API
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                        // keep track of access token expiration
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

                        // add some other app specific claim
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            nid,
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                    },

                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                            if (idTokenHint != null)
                            {
                                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What are you expecting to time out?

Comment: Hoping that when I refresh the index page (Home/Index action) I will get redirected to log back in again.

Comment: You might be, but you've not yet timed out at IdentityServer (it has its own cookie lifetime). You might need to change the cookie lifetime at IdentityServer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                        new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
                        n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken){Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,1)};
```

this will make it re-authenticate every 1 second. I think the default is 1 minute 40 before it would need to re-authenticate.